Moove mapping code of the protobuff model to another project
I have GrpcService project, and two grpc clients with same models. I want to moove duplicate code to commonProject.
Project
But when i try to use common method of mapping protobuff model to Dto I've got an error.
Error
proto file
UserDto and GetUserDtoFromGrpcProtoUser
I tryed to use auto mapper and moove mapping profile to common progect but got an error too.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s.
